# Parameter 1 to wpcf7_tg_pane_checkmail() expected to be a reference, value given in

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I have WP plugin called check email validation.

This plugin adds a new field in Contact Form 7 called "Checkmail" that allow to do a double email check when submitting the form. The new field will ask users to confirm their email by typing it into a second field.

But the plugin support is not available and it's not working with latest contact form 7.

While when I try to add the Checkmail field in contact from backend, it gives me the error

Warning: Parameter 1 to wpcf7_tg_pane_checkmail() expected to be a reference, value given in /home/autowash/public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/admin/includes/tag-generator.php on line 68

anyone here can help me in this issue. I found the code in my plugin file.

```
function WPCF7_tg_pane_checkmail( &$contact_form ) {
?>
<div id="WPCF7-tg-pane-checkmail" class="hidden">
<form action="">

<table>
<tr><td><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Name', 'WPCF7' ) ); ?><br /><input type="text" name="name" class="tg-name oneline" /></td><td></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><code>id</code> (<?php echo esc_html( __( 'optional', 'WPCF7' ) ); ?>)    <br />
<input type="text" name="id" class="idvalue oneline option" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><?php echo esc_html( __( 'Email field name to check', 'WPCF7' ) ); ?><br /><input type="text" name="values" class="oneline" /></td>

</tr>
</table>

<div class="tg-tag"><?php echo esc_html( __( "Copy this code and paste it into the form left.", 'WPCF7' ) ); ?><br /><input type="text" name="checkmail" class="tag" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.select()" /></div>

<div class="tg-mail-tag"><?php echo esc_html( __( "And, put this code into the Mail fields below.", 'WPCF7' ) ); ?><br /><span class="arrow">&#11015; </span>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="mail-tag" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.select()" /></div>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I see the code you are calling?  The problem is your code is calling the function and passing a value such as a string variable or int or boolean or null.  You need to pass the reference to variable.  Or you can remove the '&' from your function call in front of $contact_form.

Comment: i figure out the issue, i have removed the & and it start to working now and removed the class="hidden" so its start appear now. but i have problem occuring of refreshing the tag  not working. so i match the code in contact form module tags. now code is refreshing fine but now its not validating the from [link](http://www.xesense.com/contact/)